# oracle append rows to main query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Forgive the title, didn't know how to phrase it better.
Here is my issue.
I have 2 tables, Employee and Address as below, Empi_Id is the primary key in Employee table and foreign key in Address table. I need a query which will fetch the result as shown in Expected result It should concatenate all the street and phone of an Employee Id into one row. Please advise.
[image]

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @Ramki - please edit or delete your comment. There is no such thing as string_aggregate() in Oracle. Also, the problem the original poster a shed about does not require a join.

Comment: hi , you can use LISTAGG() function and gropu by emp ID and join with Emploee table . check some example of LISTAGG() .  My above comment saying STRING_AGGREGATE() is wrong . Thanks for pointing out my mistake.